# Labeling Fliers/Outliers in Matplotlib Box Plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I'm creating a box and whisker plot using matplotlib, and would like to label the outlier dots of this box and whisker plot. Is this possible? I haven't found any documentation on it.

[Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nO8Dr.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Yes it's possible, but provide your code/data to be able to reproduce it.